# How can I read an encrypted private key in an sftp producer?

Tags: apache-camel, sftp, private-key

I'm trying to upload a file to an sftp holding a public key. I have the private key in my project I generated through `ssh-keygen` with a passphrase set. I have tried this:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
        var connection =
                sftpProperties
                        .getSftpForEntity("target")
                        .orElseThrow(SftpProperties.noSuchEntity("target"));


        var privateKey = ArrayUtils.toObject(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("src/main/resources/id_rsa")));



        from(
                file("test")
        )
                .to(
                        sftp(connection.getConnectionString("/hello"))
                                .username(connection.getUser())
                                .privateKeyPassphrase("pass")
                                .privateKey(privateKey)
                );
    }
}
```

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://arcapptest@us2.hostedftp.com:22
...
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@71068da
```

It seems like the passphrase isn't being applied. I've also tried this:

```
.to(
                        sftp(floridaConnection.getConnectionString("/hello"))
                                .username(floridaConnection.getUser())
                                .privateKeyPassphrase("pass")
                                .privateKeyFile("src/main/resources/id_rsa") 
                );
```

with same result.

I've tried using the unencrypted private key, and that works.

Comment: I'm not sure you can encrypt the private key with anything (pgp) and expect everything to work. You can use `openssl` to encrypt the private key with something more usable

Comment: I took your advice: made a new key pair using `ssh-keygen` and supplied passphrase. After, I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the encryption of the private key. Camel uses JSch to deal with the key, and it needed to be PEM. I converted the key using this: `ssh-keygen -p -f /path/to/key -m pem`. After, the passphrase could be used to read the key.